# Create index on a view with "Latest record of group" select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexed-view

I'm trying to improve performance of my views using indexed views, however I'm not sure if I can overcome the limitations.

In my view I'm trying to select latest records for a particular group. I'm able to write such query either using inner select or using common table expression with row_number() OVER..PARTITION BY.

**However, both of these approaches prevents from creating index on the view.** Is there any other way how to write the view so that I can create index on it?

```
SELECT [Person ID], [Updated DateTime], Email
FROM   dbo.[People Information History] AS [People Information]
WHERE  ([People Information].[Updated DateTime] =
            (SELECT        MAX([Updated DateTime]) AS Expr1
            FROM            dbo.[People Information History]
            WHERE        ([People Information].[Person ID] = [Person ID])))
```

or

```
WITH [Current  Information]
AS
(
    SELECT [Person ID], [Updated DateTime], Email,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [Updated DateTime] ORDER BY [Updated DateTime] DESC) as RowNum
    FROM dbo.[People Information History]
)

SELECT [Person ID], [Updated DateTime], Email
FROM   [Current  Information]
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: what are your indexes on people information history?

Comment: PK Clustered on (Person Id and Updated Date Time) and the Non clustered on Email and couple of other columns that I have ommited

Comment: You cannot. The rules around indexed views are there to mean that the view can be maintained *purely* from the actual rows affected by any particular DML statement. But if the latest row is deleted here, there's no way to know what the "new" latest row to substitute in is without scanning the entire base table.

Comment: Have you ran this query through Query Analyzer?  It might give you a simple index that increases your performance significantly.

Comment: This is a problem I have tried very very hard to solve. [Here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/devops/database-devops/yet-another-sql-strategy-for-versioned-data/) is an excellent article by Alex Kuznetsov, and [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19366/43861) on StackExchange DBA which refers to some other relevant solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You should create indexes on your real tables.

It seems wrong with your second script ，like this:

```
PARTITION BY [Person ID]
```

reference [Create Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: If I should create indexed on real tables, what are indexed views good for? Person ID is not unique in `[People Information History]` table. And overall, I don't understand what is wrong in my `PARTITION BY`. Could you be more specific?